# Proving $f(x,y)\geq g(x,y)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, monotone-functions

In single-variable real function, For example, if we want to prove $f(x)\geq g(x)$ for any non-negative real number $x,$ one can start by checking the first derivative $f(x)-g(x)$ is nonngeative or not (to check increasing-ness). Then, (maybe) by checking that $f(0)-g(0)$ is nonnegative or not.

My question, is there any (simple) method to prove like the above for two-variable function? i.e $$f(x,y)\geq g(x,y)$$ (for example) with condition $x,y\geq 0.$

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You have derivative tests in more dimensions, see for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Applications)

Comment: Maybe I miss something but the article is mainly about second derivative. I mean in my question, how can we check that two variable real function is always non negative for example $f(x,y)\geq 0$ for all $x,y\in [0,\infty).$ thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

The analog of your example would be to check if $f(0,0)\geq 0$ and check the gradient $\nabla f(x,y)\cdot(x,y)\geq 0$ for every $(x,y)$. This will answer your question because of the following reasoning:

Let $g(t)=f(tx,ty)$. Then, by the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$f(x,y)=\int_0^1g'(t)dt +f(0,0).$$
Computing this derivative explicitly using the chain rule, you will get your answer. If you need further help, I can update my answer.